# How to force the client's browser to use of the cache?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http, caching

Regards.

The situation is the next:

1. I have a php page with a few images that are repeated continuously.
2. These images are distributed dynamically in differents positions (I guess it has nothing to do with my problem) and they are showed like simple icons with pure html through an 'img' tag and a default url.
3. I don't want the browser to download the images each time the page is updated-refreshed.

I tried headers but it doesn't work. Although I'm not sure if I did right and if it's convenient for this problem. So my solution was reduce the size of these images but it's not enough. I was very grateful if someone help to solve this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cache for images, php, js, and html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675574/cache-for-images-php-js-and-html)

Answer (score 0):

Give the following a try:
You also need an Apache webserver with mod_expires enabled.

```
## Keep alive ##
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive
</IfModule>
## Keep alive ##

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 month"
## From here on all types are extra for your needs
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 month"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

The `1 month` period can be changed to `1 week`, `2 month`, `1 year` etc.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to enable the mod_expire module but I don't know sure what I have to do. I was reading about rewriting the httpd.conf file and put "LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so' at the end but I haven't try it yet.

Comment: + I'm using xampp for ubuntu. I guess .c files are .so for me.

Comment: I don't have much experience with ubuntu but you should be able to enable apache modules